# why am i getting Missing required field: memberKey when running AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail);?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am running a script (adapted from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) in a sheet to add/remove email addresses to a domain group. 
The insert works (so the authority/credentials work) but the remove throws an error "Missing required field: memberKey". Here is the code snippet:

```
 var groupEmail = 'members@domain.org';
  var userEmail = 'someone@gmail.com';
  var memberKey = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  try{
          member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(memberKey, groupEmail);
  }
  catch (err){
          Logger.log(err.message)
  }
  try{
          AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, memberKey);
  }
  catch (err){
          Logger.log(err.message)
  }
```

I have also tried:

AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail) instead of AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, memberKey)

which gives a different error: "Resource Not Found: memberKey"

Comment: Your example has a lot of undefined items so it's rather hard for us to figure out what's wrong.  You should read [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: done. thanks. first post.

Comment: You're supplying an object instead of a string https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/delete

Comment: so AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail) instead of AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, memberKey)? that gives error: "Resource Not Found: memberKey"

Comment: If you `.list` the members of that group, is the user in it?

Comment: no. i guess "Resource Not Found: memberKey" is the opposite of "Member already exists." thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way (tested)

```
function removeGroupUser(userEmail, groupEmail){
  AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail.toLowerCase(), userEmail.toLowerCase());
  console.log('User %s removed from group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

please note: you must test with real emails